# In a sports tournament with 16 teams, 4 groups of 4 teams, what are the odds on 4 specific teams being drawn in one specific group?

Tags: probability

For the calculation, assume that teams are drawn completely at random and the teams are drawn in following order:

GROUP A, GROUP B, GROUP C, GROUP D, GROUP A, GROUP B, GROUP C, GROUP D, GROUP A, GROUP B, GROUP C, GROUP D, GROUP A, GROUP B, GROUP C, GROUP D,

Answer (score 0):

The first team is going to be in one of the groups anyway. For the second to be in the same group the probability is 3/15, the third to be in the same group is 2/14 and the last is 1/13. These events are independent.